# How to convert and insert string value 9,999.99 to float/double in sql using php

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have arrays of data (import from excel) values in string. One of the data are accounting numbers eg: 9,999.99

my sql data type for that accounting numbers is float.
each time I insert the value.. it only store 9 instead 9,999.99
And I plan to store in format 9999.99 (without the comma)

I cannot change the sql data type to string as it will be use for calculations later on.. so how do i convert and store the data?

appreciate your suggestions.
Thanks

This is my code to insert into DB

```
// To set HMS daily collection
function set_pbb_data($sheetDataPBB)
{
    $OK = 0;
    $notOK = 0;
    $firstElement = true;

    foreach ($sheetDataPBB as $value)
    {
        if ($firstElement) {
            $firstElement = false;  
        }
        else {
            $dbEntry = array(
            'sett_date'     => $value[0],
            'trans_date'    => $value[1],
            'card_no'       => $value[2],
            'card_type'     => $value[3],
            'trans_curr'    => $value[4],
            'trans_amt'     => $value[5],
            'sett_curr'     => $value[6],
            'sett_amt'      => $value[7],
            'gross_cur'     => $value[8],
            'gross_amt'     => $value[9],
            'mdr'           => $value[10],
            'mid'           => $value[11],
            'approval_code' => $value[12],
            'status'        => $value[13],
            'tid'           => $value[14],
            'batch_no'      => $value[15],
            'dba'           => $value[16],
            'trace_no'      => $value[17],
            'prod_type'     => $value[18]
            );
            if ($value[0] != null){ 
                $this->db->insert('pbb_cc_tbl', $dbEntry);
                if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
                    $OK++;
                }
                else {  
                    echo '<script>alert(" '.$value[0].' Already Exist!");</script>';
                    $notOK++;
                }   
            }           
        } //end-if
    } //end-foreach

    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        echo '<script>alert("'.$OK.' PBB Data Added Successfully");  </script>';
    }
    else {  
        echo '<script>alert("'.$notOK.' PBB Data Already Exist!"); window.history.back();</script>';
    }       
}
```

Comment: Replace commas with an empty string …?

Comment: try `$value = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);`

Answer (score 0):

read each row in excel and insert one by one using sql query

```
 insert into database.table (value) values (cast("999,99" as decimal(9,3)));
```

Comment: the data i read is from excel.. that is why the data contain comma. I insert my code to insert data into database above

Comment: data for all field with _amt formats are 9,999.99. How do I convert it? thanks